# Getting operational error out of a insert SQLLite3

Tags: python

```
def insert(BookID,Author,BookFormatID,Title,BookStatus,Category,RedemptionCode,StudentAssignedId):
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "AVDatabase.db")
    conn=sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Books(BookID,Author,BookFormatID,Title.BookStatus,Category,RedemptionCode,StudentAssignedId) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (BookID,Author,BookFormatID,Title,BookStatus,Category,RedemptionCode,StudentAssignedId))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    view()
```

which is called by this event on a button:

```
def add_command():
    back.insert(BookId_text.get(),Author_text.get(),Book_Format_Id_text.get(),Book_Title_text.get(),Book_Status_text.get(),Category_text.get(),Redemption_Code_text.get(),Student_Assigned_Id_text.get())
    list1.delete(0,END)
    list1.insert(END,(BookId_text.get(),Author_text.get(),Book_Format_Id_text.get(),Book_Title_text.get(),Book_Status_text.get(),Category_text.get(),Redemption_Code_text.get(),Student_Assigned_Id_text.get()))
```

So basic entry widgets and im about to pull my hair.

Comment: What is the error you are getting--can you add the full error text to your question please?

Answer (score 1):

In the `insert` function, `Title.BookStatus` should be `Title, BookStatus`.

---

You might have better luck avoiding this kind of error if you use multiline strings
for long SQL:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Books(BookID
                                 , Author
                                 , BookFormatID
                                 , Title
                                 , BookStatus
                                 , Category
                                 , RedemptionCode
                                 , StudentAssignedId) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",
    (BookID, Author, BookFormatID, Title,
     BookStatus, Category, RedemptionCode, StudentAssignedId))
```